# How can I display the latest list item at the top of list in listviewbuilder (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have made an expense tracking Flutter application that records expenses and stores them in an SQLite database, displaying them within a ListViewBuilder. However, I have encountered an issue regarding the presentation of transactions. To ensure that the most recent transactions consistently appear at the top, I used the "reverse: true" attribute of listviewbuilder. Unfortunately, this adjustment has caused the transactions to populate from the bottom of the container.

This is the list I am fetching from sqlite:

`class txList extends StatelessWidget { final List<Map<String, dynamic>> expenses;`

And here I am using listviewbuilder:

`child: ListView.builder( reverse: true,`

till the length of expenses:

`itemCount: expenses.length,`

[Without reverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkC4V.jpg)

[The result I am getting with "reverse: true"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Xe8.jpg)

My objective is to have transactions populate from the top of the container, with the most recent entry always displayed at the top and the previous one below.

[Same elements order but populating from the top of the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRe4h.jpg)

Comment: TODO: 1. Please add a date field in your data model. The date is considered as your last added date with time as well

Comment: 2. then sort the data on the basis of the date field in descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse is made on the ListBuilder which mean that the widget will be reversed not the list. In order for the list to be reversed, you can maintain a new list in your state and affect it with `var reversedList = yourFisrtList.reversed.toList()`

Comment: Thanks, it worked after making a new list and reversing the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

just what you have to do is display your `list items` from the `last index` in the `listViewBuilder`

```
    List<int> numberList = List.generate(10,(index)=> index);

    ListView.builder(
      itemCount: numberList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(numberList[numberList.length-1-index].toString()),
        );
      },
    ),
```